# How implementing factory design pattern in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, factory-pattern

How can I implement the factory design pattern in Ocaml in both ways :

functionnal and object ?

F# benefits from the keyword "abstract" so it's rather easy but not Ocaml

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://people.csail.mit.edu/dnj/teaching/6898/projects/vicente-wagner.pdf) contains implementations of various design patterns in OCaml, including both Abstract Factory and Factory Method patterns.

When implementing an object-oriented version of the Abstract Factory pattern, the `virtual` keyword can be used in place of `abstract` (on both methods and classes).

Comment: I think the article is a little out of date: "In ML, modules and classes are not first class objects." OCaml provides first class citizenship for modules since 3.12 so it is _very_ easy to implement a factory with that.